# Why this Apache Beam pipeline reading an Excel file and creating a .CSV from it is not working?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am pretty new in Apache Beam and I am experiencing the following problem with this simple task: I am trying to create a new **.csv** file staring from an **.xlsx** Excel file. To do this I am using Apache Beam with Python 3 language and **Pandas** library. I admit that are all topic pretty new to me.

I am working on Google Colab but I think that this is not so significant as information.

I imported Apache Beam and Pandas in this way (the ! is only the way to give shell command to Google Colab):

```
!{'pip install --quiet apache-beam pandas'}
```

And this is my Python code implementing the Apache Bean pipeline:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import pandas as pd

def parse_excel(line):
  # Use the pandas library to parse the line into a DataFrame
  df = pd.read_excel(line)
  print("DATAFRAME")

  # Convert the DataFrame to a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a row in the DataFrame
  # and has keys that are the column names and values that are the cell values
  return [row.to_dict() for _, row in df.iterrows()]

def print_json(json_object):
  # Print the JSON object
  print(json_object)

def run(argv=None):
  print("START run()")
  p = beam.Pipeline()

  # Read the Excel file as a PCollection
  lines = (
             p 
             | 'Read the Excel file' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('Pazienti_export_reduced.xlsx')
             | "Convert to pandas DataFrame" >> beam.Map(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x))
             | "Write to CSV" >> beam.io.WriteToText(
                'data/csvOutput', file_name_suffix=".csv", header=True
            )
          )
  
  print("after lines pipeline")

  # Parse the lines using the pandas library
  #json_objects = lines | 'ParseExcel' >> beam.Map(parse_excel)

  # Print the values of the json_objects PCollection
  #json_objects | 'PrintJSON' >> beam.ParDo(print_json)
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("START main()")
  print(beam.__version__)
  print(pd.__version__)
  run()
```

When I run it I obtain no error but my **data** folder still empty. Basically it seems that the expected **csvOutput.csv** output file was not created at the end of my pipeline.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your pipeline, but not running it. You need to do either

```
with beam.Pipeline(...) as p:
  ...
  # p.run() called on __exit__
```

or

```
p = beam.Pipeline(...)
...
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Note that `beam.io.ReadFromText` does not work on xlsx files, and likewise `WriteToText` does not not accept as input a PCollection of Pandas Dataframes. (It would be clearer if Python were strongly typed.) Instead, what you might want to do is something like

```
with beam.Pipeline(...) as p:
  filenames = p | beam.Create(['Pazienti_export_reduced.xlsx', ...])
  rows_as_dicts = filenames | beam.Map(filenames, parse_excel)
  csv_lines = csv_lines | beam.Map(
      lambda row: ','.join(str(row[c]) for c in [COL_NAMES]))
  csv_lines | beam.WriteToText('out.csv', header=...)
```

Even easier would be to use the beam [dataframes API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/)

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_excel

with beam.Pipeline(...) as p:
  data = p | read_excel("/path/to/*.xlsx")
  data.to_csv("out.csv")
```